# Java equal vs == (String Instance Variable)

Tags: java

As I know == basically compares memory location, So I totally understand that line 1 is returning true. But we have not overridden the equal method in class , then why line 2 is  returning true?

```
private String category = "procedura1";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lang obj1 = new Lang();
    Lang obj2 = new Lang();
    if (obj1.category == obj2.category) {  ///  Line 1
        System.out.println("Equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not equal");
    }
    if (obj1.category.equals(obj2.category)) {  /// Line 2
        System.out.println("Equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not equal");
    }
}
```

And Why line 3 of following  returning false?

```
    String a1 = new String("String 1");
    String a2 = new String("String 1");

    if (a1 == a2) {      // Line 3
        System.out.println("True");
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");

    }

    if (a1.equals(a2)) {
        System.out.println("True");
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");

    }
```

Comment: @almasshaikh:  It's not.

Comment: You are comparing the Strings so you are using String.equals.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `category` is of type `String` which uses the `String equals()` implementation.

Comment: So, string data type automatically calling String class?

Comment: @RobinPaul String is not a primitive data type, it is an object. So yes.

Comment: I have added a new code, why line 3 is returning false?

Comment: As they point to different locations in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're overlooking the custom object entirely and going to a field that has an `equals` method defined.

If you were doing something like this instead:

```
if(obj1.equals(obj2))
```

...you would have an issue if `equals` isn't defined on `Lang`.  But, as we know, `equals` is indeed defined on `String`, so you would see it working just fine.

This is, of course assuming that `category` actually *is* `String`; I'm only inferring it for now.

Comment: category is listed in the post as a String.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `category` field is a String *literal*, which is [*interned*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), so every instance's category refers to the *same* String object, hence they are equal according to `==`.

The contract for `equals()` is that it return true when called on itself, and you can rely on classes from the JDK honouring this contract.

Answer (score 0):

It's true 'cause you're basically comparing the two thing properties.. That's equivalent to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "procedura1";
    String str2 = "procedura1";

    if (str1.equals(str2)) {
        System.out.print("Both String objects represent the same sequence of characters");
    }
}
```

But if  you may compare it this was:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lang obj1 = new Lang();
    Lang obj2 = new Lang();

    if (obj1.equals(obj2)) {
        System.out.println("Both Lang objects are equal.");
    }
}
```

You won't get any message.. hope this helps ;)